# how to read in file in lines of three?

Tags: php, file, io

So, say you have a php post script that appends whatever you pass to it to a text file as a new line

Let say the file is called file.txt and looks like this:

```
11:45 Am
12:49 PM
Went to Lunch
3:25 PM
```

I wanna know, how can I write a php script that treats information as pairs of 3.
so in a for loop it would display

```
line1 | line2 | line3
line4
```

Notice that there is nothing past line4, so it stopped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2I7QxD))

```
$chunksOfThree = array_chunk(file('/path/to/file', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES), 3);
foreach ($chunksOfThree as $chunk) {
    echo implode(' | ', $chunk), PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will output the desired

```
11:45 Am | 12:49 PM | Went to Lunch
3:25 PM
```

See the Manual entries for

- [`file` — Reads entire file into an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and
- [`array_chunk` — Split an array into chunks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)
- [`implode` — Join array elements with a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Thank you for the demo. Works great. I had to replace PHP_EOL with <br/>. Not sure why. But it works great now.

Comment: @user1048138 because you are viewing the file in a browser while `PHP_EOL` is the system-specific newline character, e.g. ignored by browsers unless you wrap it into `<pre>` elements or CSS-format the enclosing element with `white-space:pre`

Answer (score 1):

[fgets](http://php.net/fgets) reads an entire line from the file.  It is slower than something like [fread](http://php.net/fread) but does what you want.

You can also use the [file](http://php.net/file) function to read the whole file into an array.  Each element in the array corresponds to a line in the file.

If the number of lines read is not a multiple of 3, just ignore the last 1 or 2 lines.

`fgets` returns false if there is no more data so you can check that to determine if one of the triplet entries is incomplete.

```
while(!feof($fp)) {
    $line1 = fgets($fp);
    $line2 = fgets($fp);
    $line3 = fgets($fp);

    if ($line2 === false) {
        echo "$line1";
    } else if ($line3 == false) {
        echo "$line1 | $line2";
    } else {
        echo "$line1 | $line2 | $line3\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for this

```
<?php
$filename = "test.txt";
$fp = fopen( $filename, "r" ) or die("Couldn't open $filename");
$i=0;
while ( ! feof( $fp ) ) {
   $line = fgets( $fp, 1024 );
   if($i==2)
   {
      print "$line";
      $i=0;
      print "<br>";
   }
   else
   {
      print "$line | ";
      $i++;
   }
}
?>

Output : 

11:45 Am | 12:49 PM | Went to Lunch 
3:25 PM |
```

Comment: you can take one integer variable that initially zero and into while loop you can check that if that this variable is equal to 2 then put one <br/> tag